# Multiple namespaces for IApplicationEnvironment yet the names spaces don't exist

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm currently in the process of attempting to upgrade a vNext project from beta4 to beta5 and am having troubles with some fixes in order to get the project to build. For starters I'm not even attempting this in my actually project, and am just upgrading the new mvc app from VS2015 CPT.

The problem that I'm having at the moment involves the configuration and as I understand it changes have been made to how configuration files are loaded and parse, however when I attempt to make the required changes as suggested here: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/25 I get an odd error where VS tells me that the interface exists in both Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Abstractions and Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Interfaces but both of these namespace don't appear to exist.

To make things more confusing when I view the object browser I can see exactly what I want and the Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Abstractions namespace shows up in my project just fine, however if I try to actually use it again VS tells me its not there.

I have also done a dun restore and a dun build however these don't help me at all at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Check your project.json file.
No package can't depend on old library.
All Microsoft package must be beta5 version.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Interfaces is a beta4 nuget dependency. In beta5 you must remove that and replace it with Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Abstractions.

I can tell you from my own multi project solution that I upgraded from beta4 to beta5, the only way I could get past build errors was by removing the target for dnx451 and only targeting dnxcore50, as seen [in my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31234888/cant-seem-to-get-class-library-projects-to-build-after-upgrading-aspnet-5-from)